# Chain Rule example from lecture

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

If $$v = \frac{y}{x},$$

then

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = v + x\frac{dv}{dx},$$

and so

$$\frac{d ^ 2y}{dx ^ 2} = 2\frac{dv}{dx} + x\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}.$$

What are the steps to this? I don't see how my professor did it.

Comment: what is it that you don't get? could you share your attempts or thoughts?

Comment: @Fringe_Agent13 Although the suggestion previously made could certainly have been phrased in a better way, it is still a valid one. Please, make an effort and learn/use MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y=x\cdot v$ where $v$ is a function of $x$.
Hence, by differentiating the product we find
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(x\cdot v)}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dx}\cdot v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}.$$
Now we differentiate again and we obtain the next line
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d(dy/dx)}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}+\left(\frac{dv}{dx}+x\cdot\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}\right)=2\cdot\frac{dv}{dx}+x\cdot\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}.$$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was completely overthinking this. Thank you